# Laravel resetPassword() throws with "Attempt to assign property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to change the password for the current user:

```php
public function postChange(Request $request)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'oldpassword' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    if (\Hash::check($request->oldpassword, $user->password)) {
        $this->resetPassword($user->email, $request->password);
    } else {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors('The old password is incorrect.');
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

> ErrorException in ResetsPasswords.php line 134:
>
> Attempt to assign property of non-object

What do I have to change to make this work?

```php
$this->resetPassword($user->email, $request->password);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the full user object as the first argument:

```php
$this->resetPassword($user, $request->password);
```

Take a look at [Laravel's source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L111).

Comment: sorry for noob question, how can i get current user object ?